# autobahn.js file is not accessible from s3

Tags: javascript, autobahn, autobahnjs

For some time I am using autobahn.js and autobahn.min.js files in my project linked directly from:

```
https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.js and 
https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.min.js
```

as suggested on http://autobahn.ws/ website.

Today I found out the two above files are no longer accessible via these links. Only thing I can see is 403 error with message: Access Denied.

I can not find any mirrors anywhere. I tried to build them using this instruction: http://autobahn.ws/js/building.html. No such luck. Where can I find autobahn.js files so I can download them in case of situation like this happen in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answer. Unfortunately author decided to remove all the files from Amazon S3 as described: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autobahnws/aHxWgImJvCY

> Hi,
>
> we (Crossbar.io GmbH) have not only provided massive development
>   funding of AutobahnJS, but also free hosting of AutobahnJS *for
>   development purposes* (download it and host it yourself).
>
> We asked people NOT to hot link to this bucket MULTIPLE times, as we
>   have to pay for the traffic obviously.
>
> Now, it seems, people don't get that.
>
> Our traffic costs have persistently increased to a surprising level. I
>   just wanted to delete the log folder alone in that bucket - and I have
>   a hard time, the log files number in the 100k's!
>
> There seem to be a number of highly frequented sites hot linking to
>   our bucket.
>
> Now, instead of injecting some nice JavaScript to completely take over
>   *all* those sites (which is trivial and would take me half an hour to do!), we have decided to remove the whole bucket.
>
> Dozens of sites will break. Not our problem.
>
> Cheers, /Tobias

Newer source files can be still found on github (the one that implements wamp v2). Last version that implements wamp v1 (v.0.8.2 of autobahn-js) however can be found in this repo:
https://github.com/sergeyvolkov/autobahn-old

It can be hot swapped if you were using links from my question. Good source of other older versions is to digg through releases on GitHub page:
https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/releases

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js-built . They have the files

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Files in my question are from previous version of autobahn implementing wamp v1. Repo linked in your answer contains just wamp v2 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a README:
https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js-built/blob/master/README.md

Here's a summary:

Install bower:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Install autobahn in your web dir:

```
bower install autobahn
```

Change your links to point to:

```
<script src="/bower_components/autobahnjs/autobahn.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure why you replied to another comment RE wamp v1 / v2 as the URLs you posted are retrieving the latest.

Comment: Version from sergeyvolkov/autobahn-old GitHub repo is the same I was looking for (the one that was all this time on the Amazon under the links I posted in my question) version  0.8.2. GitHub repo crossbario/autobahn-js-built contains only versions 0.9.4-2 and never.